# C# How to mock DbContext without passing it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, dbcontext

I want to unit test my function `GetDogName` which creates a new `DbContext`. I already have a working `Mock` of my `DbContext`, but I can't pass it everywhere as a parameter.

I can replace the `DbContext context = new()` with something else in the function. But I don't have the possibility to pass the `DbContext` as a parameter.

I also have checked if it is possible with a factory (or something else?), but have not found a solution yet.

```cs
static class AnimalsHelper
{
    public static string GetDogName() // I can not pass parameters here
    {
        // I can change this line
        using (DbContext context = new())
        {
            return context.Dogs.First().Name;
        }
    }
}

class UnitTest
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        ContextMock = new Mock<DbContext>();
        Context     = ContextMock.Object;

        ContextMock.Setup(context => context.Dogs).Returns("Rex");
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetDogName_DogName_ReturnsRex()
    {
        var expected = "Rex";
        var actual   = AnimalsHelper.GetDogName();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't. Use your own DbContext with the in-memory provider instead. `context.Dogs` is a `DbSet<Dog>` and will never return `"Rex"` anyway. As for `I can not pass parameters here` that's an application bug, not a mocking or DbContext issue. You can't use a mock object when the method doesn't accept any input

Comment: For testing you need a way to remove/replace dependencies. And in your code its more ore less impossible. You need a different implementation pattern to make that testable. And static methods with hard coded dependencies will always be a problem.

Comment: If you want to use static methods, they need to receive their dependencies as parameters or through other static objects (which is a pain).  The current code doesn't even allow changing the connection string without recompilation. You could use a static *extension*  method that would allow you to write `myContext.GetDogName()` if the signature was `public static string GetDogName(this MyContext context)=>context.Dogs.First().Name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved this with a `DbContextCreator` class.

An instance of a `IDbContextCreator` class is created in the `Main` and this is then kept static.
The function to which a `DbContext` can **not** be passed as a parameter uses this `static` creator instance to create a new `DbContext`.
In the unit test, a creator class is used, which returns a `DbContextMock`.

This allows the function to be tested without accessing the database.

#### Main

```
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Main application entry point
    /// </summary>
    internal static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        DbContextCreator.Instance = new MyDbContextCreator();

        // Start Application
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    private class MyDbContextCreator : IDbContextCreator
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public BaseDbContext Create() => new();
    }
}
```

#### Function

```cs
public static void TestableFunction()
{
    using (BaseDbContext context = DbContextCreator.Create())
    {
        // DB stuff
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

#### Abstract Unit Test

```cs
public abstract class AbstractTestWithMockData : AbstractTest
{
    protected BaseDbContext       Context     { get; set; }
    protected Mock<BaseDbContext> ContextMock { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected AbstractTestWithMockData()
    {
        DbContextCreator.Instance = new TestDbContextCreator(this);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    [SetUp]
    public override void SetUp()
    {
        base.SetUp();

        ContextMock = new Mock<BaseDbContext>();
        Context     = ContextMock.Object;

        // ContextMock.Setup()
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    private class TestDbContextCreator : IDbContextCreator
    {
        private readonly AbstractTestWithMockData AbstractTest;

        public TestDbContextCreator(AbstractTestWithMockData abstractTest)
        {
            AbstractTest = abstractTest;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public BaseDbContext Create()
        {
            return AbstractTest.Context;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Creator `Interface` and `static` `Instance`

```cs
/// <summary>
///     Interface for a project-specific implementation of a <see cref="BaseDbContext" /> creator.<br />
///     The creator is required in order to be able to unit test functions
///     where a <see cref="BaseDbContext" /> cannot be passed as a parameter.
/// </summary>
public interface IDbContextCreator
{
    BaseDbContext Create();
}

/// <summary>
///     Static database creator that holds an instance of <see cref="IDbContextCreator" />
///     to be able to create an instance of <see cref="BaseDbContext" />.
/// </summary>
public static class DbContextCreator
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Static instance of <see cref="IDbContextCreator" /> for the <see cref="Create" /> function.
    /// </summary>
    [SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1044:Properties should not be write only")]
    public static IDbContextCreator? Instance { private get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates a new instance of <see cref="BaseDbContext" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A new instance of <see cref="BaseDbContext" /></returns>
    /// <exception cref="Exception">When the <see cref="Instance" /> is not set</exception>
    public static BaseDbContext Create()
    {
        if (Instance is null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Database creator instance is not set! Covfefe!");
        }

        return Instance.Create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class AnimalDbContext : DbContext
{
    // !!! Must be virtual
    public virtual DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalService
{
    private AnimalDbContext _context;

    public AnimalService(AnimalDbContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string GetDogName()
    {
        return _context.Dogs.FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
    }
}

[TestClass()]
public class AnimalServiceTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetDogName_DogName_ReturnsRex()
    {
        var data = new List<Dog>
        {
            new Dog { Name = "Rex" }
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Dog>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Dog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Dog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Dog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Dog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = new Mock<AnimalDbContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Dogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var service = new AnimalService(mockContext.Object);
        
        // Arrange
        var dogName = service.GetDogName();

        var actual = "Rex";

        Assert.AreEqual(actual, dogName);
    }
}
```